# Add error handling to existing Windows batch script-> to copy the newest file from a directory

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file

I found a good post here that queries for the latest sql server backup, and then copies it over to the remote server in preparation for a restore.  It's a batch file that is executed using cmd via sql agent step inside the sql restore job.  I'm looking for help in adding extra logic to the existing script below:

```
:Variables
SET DatabaseBackupPath=\\virtualserver1\Database Backups
echo.
echo Restore WebServer Database
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer\*.bak" /B /O:D') DO SET            NewestFile=%%I
copy "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer\%NewestFile%" "D:\"
```

What I'd like to add are two extra pieces.  First add some error handling to the existing script where it would first check the latest backup, but ensure its within the last 24 hours.  If it is continue to run.  If older than 24 hours, to generate an notification alert (i.e. separate batch file) if backup file is older than 24 hours.  Second to generate similar notification, if there was an issue such as not being able to reach the remote share that holds the backup.

Appreciate replies.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to check if a file was created or last modified within 24 hours. Date/time calculation is not a trivial task without conversion of the date/time strings to seconds since epoch which would make it possible to use a simple integer comparison.

There are solutions for file date comparison, see

- [Batch script to check when the newest file in a directory was created/modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445206/batch-script-to-check-when-the-newest-file-in-a-directory-was-created-modified)
- [forfiles - Delete all files older than 1 day / 24hours using creation date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710628/forfiles-delete-all-files-older-than-1-day-24hours-using-creation-date)

You may use one of those solutions.

Much easier is to check if copy process worked:

```
copy /V "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer\%NewestFile%" "D:\"
if errorlevel 1 goto CopyFail
goto :EOF

:CopyFail
echo.
echo Copying file "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer\%NewestFile%" failed!
pause
```

---

### Solution using WinRAR

My solution below is based on usage of `Rar.exe`, the console version of **WinRAR** as this compression tool has the feature to compress only files based on file dates. Therefore this solution is only helpful for you if you have installed **WinRAR** and bought a license of it.

The path of the program files folder of **WinRAR** must be set at top of the following batch file.

```
@echo off
SET DatabaseBackupPath=\\virtualserver1\Database Backups
SET WinRarFolder=C:\Program Files\WinRAR
cls
echo.
echo Restore WebServer Database
echo.
rem Find newest *.bak file in backup directory on server.
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR /B /O-D "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer\*.bak"') DO (
   SET NewestFile=%%I
   goto BackupFound
)
cls
echo.
echo Restore WebServer Database
echo.
echo There is no *.bak file in "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer\"
echo or the backup directory on server cannot be reached at all.
goto EndBatch

:BackupFound
echo Newest backup in "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer"
echo is the file "%NewestFile%".
echo.
if exist "%TEMP%\ServerBackup.rar" del "%TEMP%\ServerBackup.rar"
"%WinRarFolder%\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep -inul -m0 -tn24h -y "%TEMP%\ServerBackup.rar" "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer\%NewestFile%"
if errorlevel 1 goto OldBackup

"%WinRarFolder%\Rar.exe" e -cfg- -inul -y "%TEMP%\ServerBackup.rar" F:\Temp
if errorlevel 1 goto ExtractFailed

del "%TEMP%\ServerBackup.rar"
echo File "%NewestFile%" copied to D:\
goto EndBatch

:ExtractFailed
del "%TEMP%\ServerBackup.rar"
echo "Copying file "%NewestFile%" to D:\ failed.
goto EndBatch

:OldBackup
echo File "%NewestFile%" is older than 24 hours.

:EndBatch
set WinRarFolder=
SET DatabaseBackupPath=
SET NewestFile=
echo.
pause
```

**Explanation:**

The batch file first uses command **DIR** to get a list of *.bak files in the specified directory sorted according to last modification file date from newest to oldest.

With the **FOR** loop the name of the file name at top of the list (= newest file) is assigned to environment variable *NewestFile*.

The batch file outputs an error message if no *.bak file can be found in the specified directory, for example if the server cannot be reached at all at the moment with the permissions of the used user account.

But on success on finding a *.bak file in specified directory, the batch file informs the batch file user which file was found in which directory.

After making sure that the RAR archive to create next does not already exist in directory for temporary files, `Rar.exe` is used to create a RAR archive in directory for temporary files into which only the found file is stored without compression, but only if this file has a last modification date within 24 hours because of switch `-tn24h`.

For details on the switches used on `Rar.exe` see text file **Rar.txt** in program files directory of **WinRAR**.

`Rar.exe` exits with an return value greater 0 if there is any problem on creating the RAR archive. In this case the reason is most likely that the specified file is older than 24 hours which results now in an appropriate message written into the console window.

`Rar.exe` is on success on creating the RAR archive without compression used once more to extract the file to target directory.

An appropriate error mesage is shown in unlikely case that this fails. Otherwise the batch file outputs a success message and finishes with cleaning up environment table (not really needed if command prompt window closed next).

The temporarily used RAR archive is deleted in any case.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer.  I will go over what I have and see if the WinRAR section will work for me..at least the error handling you mentioned will help for the copying process.